# Search missing rowId in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

In my table there are rows that have been deleted. How can I find the first missing id?

Ex:

```
ID    DATA
1    row1
2    row2
4    row3
8    row4
```

How can I find that Id 3 is missing?
This needs to run on android 3.0 minimum

Comment: Why do you think you need the first missing ID?

Comment: I need to generate a unique Id so I can insert a new row. The generated Id must be between 1 and 99999 because rows after 99999 are reserved or already used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you can use the following query to find the first unused ID in a specific range:

```
WITH RECURSIVE all_ids(id) AS (
  VALUES(1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id + 1
  FROM all_ids
  LIMIT 99999
)
SELECT id
FROM all_ids
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MyTable
                  WHERE rowid = all_ids.id)
LIMIT 1
```

In earlier SQLite versions, you cannot dynamically generate values. However, the desired ID is one larger than an already existing ID, so you can just take the IDs from the table and check whether the next one exists (the zero is a special case to handle an empty table):

```
SELECT id + 1
FROM (SELECT 0 AS id
      UNION ALL
      SELECT rowid
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE rowid <= 99999
     ) AS ids
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MyTable
                  WHERE rowid = ids.id + 1)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It needs to run on android 3.0 which have SQLite 3.7.4.

Comment: I ended up doing a for loop in java and query each id until one is not found . May not be the best solution but probably sqlite will do something similar.